# UIWebView still active after pressing back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using a Navigationcontroller which pushes a new Viewcontroller containing a Webview every time a link is clicked. One of the URLs has a javascript function, which calls another function every 60 seconds. It works fine, but when I hit the back button once after being on that web view (containing the javascript), the webview stays active and keeps doing the javascript calls, while going back to the previous webview flawlessly. I can see it doing things through NSLog. Why is that and how can I avoid this?

EDIT:

I have declared my subclass of UIWebView in my Viewcontroller like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AFXTWebView *wv;
```

and this is how I instantiate it (in ViewDidLoad):

```
    [self setWv:[[AFXTWebView alloc] initWithVC:self andURLString:[self.pageConfig objectForKey:xAFXTPageLink]]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.wv];    

    [self.wv loadWebView];
```

I have also tried setting the webView to nil in viewWillDisappear:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.wv = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the viewWillAppear & viewWillDisappear methods

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
_webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
......//do your stuff
}


-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[_webView removeFromSuperView];
_webView=nil;
}
```

Comment: Does your AFXTWebView perform anything on queue/NSOperation/blocks?

Comment: No, I'm not doing anything like that :-(. the removeFromSuperView also didn't work, except showing a blank page when navigating back.

Comment: still i dint get any idea what is going on that AFXTWebview Class

Comment: It's just a subclass of UIWebView, nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewWillDisappear` load a blank page into the web view.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your web view and view controller are not being released, i.e. you have a leak. You should check your code for any unreleased retained/strong references to your view controller or web view.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think is the problem. But I just can't figure it out :-(. I have updated my answer so you can see how I'm instantiating the Webview. Any thoughts on that? Thanks

Comment: Is the AFXTWebView class storing a strong reference to the view controller?

Comment: Yes, I made it a strong reference

Comment: That sounds like your problem then. If both objects have a strong reference to each other (view controller <-> web view), neither will ever be released. Make your web view's reference to the view controller weak, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I tried this, but then my webview always just stayed white without showing any content

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
  [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]]; 
}
```